# Bootloader fails to load kernel beyond specified memory location

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, bootloader

I'm encountering an issue with my bootloader code where it fails to load the kernel beyond a certain memory location, specifically at `KERNEL_LOCATION equ 0x100000`. When attempting to boot using QEMU, I receive the error message "boot failed: could not read the boot disk."

Here's the relevant part of my bootloader code:

```
[org 0x7c00]

KERNEL_LOCATION equ 0x100000
BOOT_DISK equ 0

xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov bp, 0x9000
mov sp, bp


call read_disk

init_pm:
    mov ax, 0x0003
    int 10h

    cli
    lgdt [GDT_descriptor]

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp CODE_SEG:start_protected_mode

%include "gdt.asm"
%include "read_disk.asm"

[bits 32]
start_protected_mode:
    mov eax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, eax
    mov ss, eax
    mov es, eax
    mov fs, eax
    mov gs, eax

    mov ebp, KERNEL_LOCATION      ; 32 bit stack base pointer
    mov esp, ebp

    jmp dword KERNEL_LOCATION     ; Jump to the kernel's entry point

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

here is the read disk function:

```
read_disk:

    ; bios read functions
    mov ah, 0x02

    ; reading just one sector
    mov al, 10

    ; chs addressing
    mov ch, 0x00 ; cylender
    mov dh, 0x00 ; head
    mov cl, 0x02 ; sector (reading the first sector after the boot sector sectors start at 1)


    ; setting the bx to the address we want to load our read disk
    mov bx, KERNEL_LOCATION

    mov dl, BOOT_DISK

    int 0x13  
    ; jump to error handler if c flag is one
    ; jc disk_error

    ; returning to the caller address
    ret

; error handler
disk_error:
    mov bx, error_msg
    ;call print_string
    jmp $

error_msg:
    ; null terminating string :)
    db "error reading disk",0
```

The read_disk function seems to be functioning properly, as it loads the boot sector correctly. However, when trying to load the kernel at 0x100000, it fails.

Notably, if I specify a lower memory location, such as 0x1000, the bootloader boots properly.

Any insights into why the bootloader fails to load the kernel beyond 0x100000 would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `bx` is a 16 bit register. You can't put `0x100000` into it.

Comment: @Jester but it doesnt work even if i try to load it at 0xf000

Comment: 0xf000 doesn't work because you read 10 sectors and that crosses a 64KiB DMA boundary so it fails. It should probably work there if you read 8 and that would fill up from 0xf000 to 0xffff. You can't read above 0x100000 because int 0x13/ah=2 is limtetd to addresses below that memory address. In this case 0x100000 doesn't fit in a 16-bit register as Jester points out.

Comment: A correct way to load a kernel at 0x100000 is: determine the actual size of the kernel (e.g. load the file's header into a temporary buffer), check if there's any/enough memory at 0x100000 using memory map from BIOS; then do { use BIOS to load a piece into a temporary buffer that real mode can access, switch to protected mode, ensure A20 gate is enabled, copy the piece where you wanted it, then switch back to real mode } until all pieces of the kernel are loaded. Note that real mode addressing is limited to "0xFFFF:0xFFFF = 0x0010FFEF" and must fail if kernel becomes larger than 65520 bytes.